# Design View is Gone! How Do I Modify My List Views Now?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, list, custom-field-types

I have just recently moved into using SharePoint 2013 and 2013 designer.  On my 2010 SP list, I have custom priority indicators which require me to open the list view in SPD and modify the valueof XLT tag to show the HTML in my calculated columns by adding disable-output-escaping="yes".  I am sure some of you have run into this problem.  How do I manipulate the tags in my views now?

Comment: Calculated columns should display in views without needing disable-output-escaping attribute. Are to referring to creating a newform, editform or display form?

Comment: No.  I just need the HTML to render from the calculated column.  I just got the software yesterday and was playing around in it.  If I do not need it then GREAT!  I will give it a shot.  No Design View still sucks a$$ though.

Comment: It does not render the HTML.  I am going to need the disable-output-escaping="yes" it is just showing the code in the column as expected without modifying the valueof tag.

Comment: Agreed, I don't like the lack of design view in 2013 either. If the list came from 2010 have you tried recreating the view in 2013? In our migration from 2010 to 2013 this was the solution when views didn't render correctly. As a last resort you could recreate the list in 2013--I know that's never ideal but for us was sometimes faster. Also is what is the value of your calculated column; what types of values is it trying to display?

Comment: @ams it is not the view, it is the calculated columns.  In order to show HTML within the list, you had to modify the tags of the XSLT to allow the HTML to render.  There has got to be a way to do this.

Comment: @lazoDev I don't see why you need the design mode to simply add the disable-output-escaping attribute to the desired tag. Can't you do it in code view?

Comment: I guess you have not looked at the code view in SPD 2013 (which one would think to be the first place to look, especially since I have done this in SPD 2010 a thousand times) all it shows is the list viewer web part information and the is it.  Hence the reason for my question.  I have figured it out anyways.

Answer (score 0):

I have found a workaround [here](http://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2012/10/31/trick-or-treat-text-to-html-the-wicked-no-code-way-part-ii/) for my problem.  Damn SharePoint for making it difficult to do what should be simple things.  The workaround is to create a workflow that drops the HTML data from the calculated field, into anther multiline field with enhanced text.  Dirty, but works like a charm.